# script mathematical mesh with xyz function surface, each coordinate parametric with u,v

Tags: python, scripting

Circa 2015, in the python script window we could enter:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(x="...", y="....", z=….",\
range_u_max=1, range_v_max=1)  # with u,v each ranging from 0 to 1
```

This fundamental and no-nonsense capability seems removed from Blender 2.8
Do we still have this capability, and if so, under what API name?

Comment: Have you enabled the Add Mesh Extra Objects addon?  It may not have been bundled in this addon in 2015, yet IIRC would have still needed to be enabled to have operator available.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124836/mathematical-functions-for-mesh-in-blender-2-8-beta

Comment: Thanks much, yes I enabled the add extra mesh objects add on.  I get the default "sea shell" but cannot change to my own shape. What's missing from the following?  
import bpy ; from math import * ; two_pi = 2 * pi ;
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(x_eq = "v", y_eq = "sin(two_pi*u)", z_eq = "cos(two_pi*u)")